# Transform hierarchical CSV data to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a csv table describing child-parent relationships of this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cjoA.jpg):

```
CHILD PARENT
1     7
2     7
2     8
3     8
4     8
5     10
6     10
7     11
8     11
8     root
9     12
10    12
11    root
12    root
```

How to transform this into this json file?

```py
graph = 
{"name":"root", "children":[
     {"name":"11", "children":[
          {"name":"7", "children":[ 
              {"name":"1"},
              {"name":"2"}
          ]},
         {"name":"8", "children":[
             {"name":"2"},
             {"name":"3"},
             {"name":"4"}
         ]},
     ]},
    {"name":"8", "children":[
        {"name":"2"},
        {"name":"3"},
        {"name":"4"}
    ]},
    {"name":"12", "children":[
        {"name":"9"},
        {"name":"10", "children":[
            {"name":"5"},
            {"name":"6"}
        ]}
    ]}
]}
```

Notice this is the flare.json format but the data in the csv is not a tree like the flare dataset. Nodes in the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cjoA.jpg) can have more than 1 parent, which ends in duplication (See node 2 and 8 in json above).
My first attempt was to create a recursive function, but I haven't been able to come up with a working solution. Any solution, recursive or not, is appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Update your question to **show what you have already tried** in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple data structures - recursive descent of unbalanced tree.

```
import io

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """CHILD PARENT
1     7
2     7
2     8
3     8
4     8
5     10
6     10
7     11
8     11
8     root
9     12
10    12
11    root
12    root"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
)


def traverse(parent, d):
    return {
        **{
            "name": parent,
        },
        # only create "children" key if node has some children
        **{
            k: [
                traverse(c, d)
                for c in d.loc[d["PARENT"].eq(str(parent)), "CHILD"]
            ] for k in ["children"] if len(d.loc[d["PARENT"].eq(str(parent))])>0
        },
    }


traverse("root", df)
```

#### output

```
{'name': 'root',
 'children': [{'name': 8, 'children': [{'name': 2}, {'name': 3}, {'name': 4}]},
  {'name': 11,
   'children': [{'name': 7, 'children': [{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}]},
    {'name': 8, 'children': [{'name': 2}, {'name': 3}, {'name': 4}]}]},
  {'name': 12,
   'children': [{'name': 9},
    {'name': 10, 'children': [{'name': 5}, {'name': 6}]}]}]}
```